# Crosstab query to show the working hours per day for each Vessel

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have made a Crosstab Query that should give information about the total working hours in each day for every Vessel we had in our small harbor.

my query:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Main.WorkingH) AS SumOfWorkingH
SELECT DateValue([DeptDate]) AS [Date]
FROM Vessels INNER JOIN Main ON Vessels.ID = Main.VesselID
GROUP BY DateValue([DeptDate])
ORDER BY DateValue([DeptDate])
PIVOT Vessels.Vessel;
```

the problem here is this query is returning the total working hours start from departure date

```
|     +---------------+--------+----+----+----+----+----+----+                                                                                     |
|     |               |        |    |    |    |    |    |    |                                                                                     |
|     +---------------+--------+----+----+----+----+----+----+                                                                                     |
|     |     Date      |     A1 | A2 | A3 | F3 | F4 | F5 | F6 |                                                                                     |
|     |     26-May-17 |        |    | 32 | 29 |    |    |    |                                                                                     |
|     |     27-May-17 | 3      | 13 |    |    |    |    |    |                                                                                     |
|     |     28-May-17 |        |    |    |    |    |    | 73 |                                                                                     |
|     |     29-May-17 |        |    |    | 12 | 6  | 27 |    |                                                                                     |
|     |     01-Jun-17 |        |    | 10 |    | 7  | 41 |    |                                                                                     |
|     |     02-Jun-17 |        | 2  | 15 | 5  |    |    |    |                                                                                     |
|     |     03-Jun-17 |        | 4  |    |    |    |    |    |                                                                                     |
|     +---------------+--------+----+----+----+----+----+----+                                                                                     |
```

**The desired Result**

when a vessel leaves at 6/1 9pm and arrive back at 6/3 10am. This should appear as following:

```
6/1-->3Hours
6/2-->24Hours
6/3-->10Hours
**NOT** 6/1-->37Hours as in the previous table.
```

This is how it should look like

```
|     +----------------+-----+----+----+----+--------+----+----+                                                                                   |
|     |        Date    |  A1 | A2 | A3 | F3 |   F4   | F5 | F6 |                                                                                   |
|     +----------------+-----+----+----+----+--------+----+----+                                                                                   |
|     |     26-May-17  |     |    |  5 |  7 |        |    |    |                                                                                   |
|     |     27-May-17  |   3 | 13 | 24 | 21 |        |    |    |                                                                                   |
|     |     28-May-17  |     |    |  2 |    |        |    |  9 |                                                                                   |
|     |     29-May-17  |     |    |    | 12 |      6 |  8 | 24 |                                                                                   |
|     |     30-May-17  |     |    |    |    |        | 18 | 24 |                                                                                   |
|     |     31-May-17  |     |    |    |    |        |    | 15 |                                                                                   |
|     |     01-Jun-17  |     |    | 10 |    |      7 |  0 |    |                                                                                   |
|     |     02-Jun-17  |     |  2 | 15 |  5 |     24 |    |    |                                                                                   |
|     |     03-Jun-17  |     |  4 |    |    |        | 16 |    |                                                                                   |
|     +----------------+-----+----+----+----+--------+----+----+                                                                                   |
```

These values are not accurate (I wrote them by hand), but I think you got the Idea

**The Suggested Solution**

while trying to fix this problem I made the following code which takes the

```
Public Function HoursByDate1(stTime, EndTime)
For dayloop = Int(EndTime) To Int(stTime) Step -1
   If dayloop = Int(stTime) Then
   WorkingHours = Hour(dayloop + 1 - stTime)
   ElseIf dayloop = Int(EndTime) Then
   WorkingHours = Hour(EndTime - dayloop)
   Else
    WorkingHours = 24
    End If
        HoursByDate1 = WorkingHours
        Debug.Print "StartDate: " & stTime & ", EndDate:" & EndTime & ", The day:" & dayloop & "  --> " & WorkingHours & " hours."
Next dayloop
End Function
```

It prints the data as following:

which is exactly what I want

But when I try to call this function from my query, It gets only the last value for each trip. as following:

```
|     +-----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+                                                                                             |
|     |   Date    | A1 | A2 | A3 | F3 | F4 | F5 | F6 |                                                                                             |
|     +-----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+                                                                                             |
|     | 5/26/2017 |    |    |  5 |  7 |    |    |    |                                                                                             |
|     | 5/27/2017 | 15 | 19 |    |    |    |    |    |                                                                                             |
|     | 5/28/2017 |    |    |    |    |    |    |  9 |                                                                                             |
|     | 5/29/2017 |    |    |    |  8 |  7 |  8 |    |                                                                                             |
|     | 6/1/2017  |    |    |  3 |    |  6 |  0 |    |                                                                                             |
|     | 6/2/2017  |    |  8 |  8 | 19 |    |    |    |                                                                                             |
|     | 6/3/2017  |    |  9 |    |    |    |    |    |
```

I seek any Solution: From VBA side of things or SQL Query Side. 
Sorry for the very long question, but I wanted to show my effort on the subject because every time I am told that this is not enough Information

Comment: Your crosstab query is grouping by departure date, which is why you are getting the sum of working hours all in one row for just the departure date.  It's not clear (to me) what data your underlying tables contain.  Adding that information to the question would make it easier to answer.

Comment: As rd_nielsen wrote, please add sample data of both input tables. It's the only (but essential) thing missing from an otherwise good question. [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271).